# Is it possible to see the different parts of file in Zend Studio 7?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, zend-studio

I want to know that, if is it possible to see the different parts of a file at the same time in Zend Studio 7? Maybe in different windows or something like that. I know this can be succeeded with simpler editors like editPlus

tHanks

Answer (score 1):

From the **Window** menu, select **New Editor**.

You can than drag the new editor from its' title tab and place it next to the original editor (horizontally or vertically). You can have as many editor windows as you want for the same file. You can place them freely within the workbench (3 files side by side, 4 files tiled, whatever works for you). You can also open a new Workbench window (Window → New Window), which is useful if you are using a multiple monitor configuration.